# /md not dynamically linking printf using msvc

Tags: c, msvcrt, msvc12

All I want is for `printf` to be dynamically linked to my exe file. Based on what I read, the switch `/MD` should be able to achieve that. However, when I look at the imports table, I do not see the printf function.

Comment: Its there, just not with the name you expected.  It handles the very large family of printf varieties with small inline functions that call a common CRT function.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you referring to an import library?